# Reopen process for https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161829?

Tags: discussion

I edited (accepted) the [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161829/is-there-a-specification-for-the-color-values-representing-information-classific) to bring it on-topic. I do not see a place to "vote to reopen".

But since the question is closed, I [edited](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/155223) the answer to provide a more accurate answer.

My edit to the answer was rejected with "submit a new answer", but cannot bacause the question is still closed as off-topic.

What is the proper process?

For those who cannot view my suggested edit, this is the edit:

---

To answer "is there a standard for on screen color values", I can say that there are none in any of the OPM, DOD, NIST, GSA, etc. instructions, rules, regulations, etc. that I have access to.

Various agencies and organizations have style guides - but website banners, application color bars, etc are vendor dependent for the color choices.

The only place color is "specified" would be in the ordering of printed supplies. Those supplies would be cover sheets and classification stickers.

Per the [U.S. Government Publishing Office General Term, Conditions, and Specifications For the Procurement of Labels](https://www.gpo.gov/docs/default-source/contract-pricing/dallas/ab1724s.pdf) from 12-Apr-2016

- NSN: 7540-01-267-1158: Form title – [SF 712 (Classified SCI)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/classified-sci-label) - [PMS 101C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/101-C) yellow ink (type reverses out and prints in black) - #F7EA48 [image: #F7EA48]
- NSN: 7540-01-207-5540: Form title – [SF 709 (Classified, level not specified)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/classified-label) - [PMS 264C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/264-C) lavender ink (type reverses out and prints in black) - #C1A7E2 - note: this is almost never used / allowed any more (e.g. DoDM 5205.07-V4, October 10, 2013) [image: #C1A7E2]
- NSN: 7540-01-207-5539: Form title – [SF 710 (Unclassified)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/unclassified-label) - [PMS 356C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/356-C) green ink (type reverses out to appear white) - #007A33 [image: #007A33]
- NSN: 7540-01-207-5538: Form title – [SF 708 (Confidential)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/confidential-label) - [PMS 286C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/286-C) blue ink (type reverses out to appear white) - #0032A0 [image: #0032A0]
- NSN: 7540-01-207-5537: Form title – [SF 707 (Secret)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/secret-label) - [PMS 186C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/186-C) red ink (type reverses out to appear white) - #C8102E [image: #C8102E]
- NSN: 7540-01-207-5536: Form title – [SF 706 (Top Secret)](https://www.gsa.gov/forms-library/top-secret-label) - [PMS 165C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/165-C) orange ink (type reverses out to appear white) - #FF6720 [image: #FF6720]

I was unable to find specifications on the cover sheets.

END EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Your edit to the question does not bring the question on topic.

While your edit did pop the question into the reopen review queue, returning was rejected in review.

You cannot answer if a question is closed.

Comment: Ok will spend a bit more time cleaning up the question - app hardening, risk management, policies, and securing information assets is on topic. The original question was to find out that information.

Comment: The original question is not about app hardening, risk management, policies or securing information assets. If you have on topic questions, ask them as new questions. Please don't edit it to change it from what it is, which is solely a question about colour standards.

Comment: I very much disagree (about the on topic) but I will open a new question, and answer it myself. I know it is on topic because the question, as asked and answered, clearly matched my question of "what are the official colors representing the different US data classifications, and what is the source reference for the policy or law?" The answer is there is no official guidance for on screen colors, but there are for in print media.

Comment: Remember, it is the US Government's opinion, and those in the US have to comply, that it is of a high impact to ensure proper marking and labeling, specifically as cited in DoD 8500, "Without the banners to identify the information system the KVM switch is currently active on, the user could enter a command to the wrong information system and create a denial of service or the user could enter data into the wrong system creating either a security incident (data entered to a system of the wrong classification) or a compromise of sensitive data."